# Tweet button data-url not updating on change

Tags: vue.js, twitter

In my vue component I am adding a twitter button to tweet a URL that I give as prop to the component:

```
  <a
    class="twitter-share-button"
    data-via="myPage"
    data-size="large"
    data-text="Check this out!"
    :data-url="`https://mywebsite.com/${shareLink}`"
    href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">
  Tweet</a>
```

I have placed the embed code in `mounted` so it gets initialized on component mount.

```
mounted () {
    this.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        t = window.twttr || {};
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

      t._e = [];
      t.ready = function(f) {
        t._e.push(f);
      };

      return t;
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
  }
```

When `shareLink` changes I expect the Tweet button to share the reactive URL but its not. The URL stays the same as it was when the component was initialized.

So I have tried different things:

1. I have used a `watcher` to watch `shareLink` changes and re-render the Tweet button. That does not work.
2. I have removed the Tweet button from the DOM and re-placed it when `shareLink` changes. No success.
3. In the parent component I have increased a `key` value to re-generate the Tweet component when `shareLink` changes. Does not work.
4. I even tried to manipulate the `data-url` directly in the generated iframe that gets served by Twitter. No success.
5. I also initialise the twitter embed code when `shareLink` changes of course

Is there anything I oversee here?

Comment: where do you first specify shareLink and how do you change it?

Comment: its build and changed in the parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem basically was that I would need to call `twttr.widgets.load()` when something in the button changes ([source](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization))

I therefore made the `twttr` code reactive itself, put it into the `data` function and refresh it via watcher when `shareLink` changes:

```
<template>
  <span v-html="tweetButton"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      tweetButton: '',
      twttr: {}
    }
  },
  props: {
    shareLink: String
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderTweetButton()
  },
  methods: {
    renderTweetButton () {

      this.tweetButton = `<a
        class="twitter-share-button"
        data-via="Example"
        data-size="large"
        data-text="Check this out!"
        data-url="https://mywebsite.com/${this.shareLink}"
        href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">
      Tweet</a>`

      this.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          t = window.twttr || {};
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

        t._e = [];
        t.ready = function(f) {
          t._e.push(f);
        };

        return t;
      }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
    }
  },
  watch: {
    shareLink () {
      this.renderTweetButton()
      this.twttr.widgets.load()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
</style>
```

This works great!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
Vue.component('BtnTwttr', {
  props: {
    shareLink: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    encodedShareLink() {
      return encodeURIComponent(`https://mywebsite.com/${this.shareLink}`)
    }
  },
  template: '  <a class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large"  :href="`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=myPage&text=Check this out!&url=${encodedShareLink}`">Tweet: {{shareLink}}</a>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    link: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    this.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        t = window.twttr || {};
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

      t._e = [];
      t.ready = function(f) {
        t._e.push(f);
      };

      return t;
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="link" /><br />
  <btn-twttr :share-link="link" />
</div>
```

This works with any string that you write in the input field. (Unfortunately you cannot really test it in StackOverflow's sandboxed environment, but I tried copying the create string and using it in the browswer.)